# Laravel pivot table - save data from additional columns

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to save data from multiple columns in pivot table. However, the data is not saving. Here is what I am doing:

**Table**

```
Schema::create('benefit_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('benefit_id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->integer('amount1')->default(0);
    $table->integer('amount2')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Blade**

```
@foreach($benefits as $benefit)
 <tr>
     <td>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{ $benefit->id }}" name="benefitId[]" id="flexCheckChecked"
        @foreach($user->benefits as $benefitId)
            {{ $benefitId->id === $benefit->id ? 'checked' : '' }}
         @endforeach
         >
      </td>
      <td>
          {{ $benefit->name }}
       </td>
       <td>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount1[]"
                @foreach($user->benefits as $e_pay)
                    value="{{ $benefitId->id === $benefit->id ? $benefitId->amount1 : '' }}"
                @endforeach
            >
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount2[]"
                @foreach($user->benefits as $er_pay)
                     value="{{ $benefitId->id === $benefit->id ? $benefitId->amount2 : '' }}"
                @endforeach
            >
        </td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

If I use checkbox only to sync *benefit_id* and *user_id*, it works. But for adding additional data *amount1* and *amount2*, its not working.

**Controller**

```
$user->benefits()->sync([$request->benefitId => ['amount1' => $request->amount1, 'amount2' => $request->amount2]]);
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what error do you get

Comment: I am getting *Illegal offset type*

Comment: did you try what I post as an answer?

Comment: Yes, got the above error

Comment: ok I will update the answer try this

Answer (score 1):

benefitId, amount1 and amount2 are array and it can't be synced your way. you need to make array from it manually, like

```
$data = [];

foreach ($request->benefitId as $index => $benefitId) {
    $data[$benefitId] => [
        'amount1' => $request->amount1[$index],
        'amount2' => $request->amount2[$index],
    ];
}

$user->benefits()->sync($data);
```

just as an idea